# Code Splitting with react-loadable gives Error : Cannot find module "."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, async-components

I'm using react-loadable v4.0.4 and webpack v3.5.1.

Here is my code,

```
import Dashboard from '../../scenes/dashboard/dashboard';    
import ReactLoadable from 'react-loadable';
...

const yoPath = 'src/components/scenes/dashboard/dashboard';

const DashboardWrap = ReactLoadable({
    loading: Dashboard,
    loader: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            require.ensure(
               [],
               (require) =>  resolve(require(yoPath)),
               (error) => reject(error),
               'dashboardChunk'
            )
         )
    }
});
```

And using react-router-dom v4.1.2, I've set Route as follows,

```
<Switch>
...
<Route exact path='/dashboard' component={DashboardWrap} />
...
</Switch>
```

I'm able to build the chunks for the respective component with the name **dashboardChunk**.

But while loading that component I'm getting the issues as follows.

[image]

In the console,

[image]

And the chunkfile,

[image]

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I basically wanted to do code splitting, for that I've just done the following and it works fine.

I've created a common component(wrapper component) as follows,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Async extends Component {
    componentWillMount = () => {
        this.props.load.then((Component) => {
            this.Component = Component
            this.forceUpdate();
        });
    }

    render = () => (
        this.Component ? <this.Component.default /> : null
    )
}

export default Async;
```

Then I've used above component as follows,

```
export const AniDemo = () => <Async load={import(/* webpackChunkName: "aniDemoChunk" */ "../../scenes/ani-demo/AniDemo.js")} />
export const Dashboard = () => <Async load={import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboardChunk" */ "../../scenes/dashboard/Dashboard.js")} />
```

And using the above, I've made the changes in route as follows,

```
<Route exact path="/ani-demo" component={AniDemo} />
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

With the help of the above changes that I made, **I'm able to create chunks properly** with the names that I've mentioned in the **comments inside import statements** ie **aniDemoChunk.js** and **dashboardChunk.js** respectively.

And **these chunks load only when the respective component is called** ie aniDemoChunk.js is loaded on browser only when AniDemo component is called or requested. Similarly for the Dashboard component respectively.

**Note:** If anyone is getting **error re:Unexpected token import.** So to support `import()` syntax just replace import to `System.import()` or else use [babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/).

Comment: Used this code. After including babel plugin also am getting the unexpected token import error. Tried system import that also not working. Using webpack 3.11 and babel-plugin 6.18

Answer (score 1):

Webpack must be able to determine the imported path during static analysis. If you pass an argument into require, this is not possible.

It is best to put the actual path into `require.ensure`, i.e.

```
require.ensure(
  ['src/components/scenes/dashboard/dashboard']
  require => 
  resolve(require('src/components/scenes/dashboard/dashboard').default)
  error => reject(error),
  'dashboardChunk'
)
```

or use the newer [dynamic import](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) syntax. With the newer syntax you could simplify the above into:

```
Loadable({ 
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboardChunk" */ 'src/components/scenes/dashboard/dashboard')
  loading: MyLoader
})
```

Also, the `loading` argument should be a component to display *while your asynchronous load is taking place*, e.g. some kind of loading animation.

Comment: I've put the actual path as well inside require.ensure. Still won't work. And thanks for your suggestion.